# Can I use Pillow and numpy in a AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use a lambda function in order to do a sagemaker prediction with an image and I need to transform from

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
object = bucket.Object(key)
response = object.get()
file_stream = response['Body']
```

to a proper format to use in

```
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, Body=json.dumps(data))
```

I did some test on a jupyter notebook and I found this commands do the job:

```
im = Image.open(file_stream)
im_array = np.array(im)
data = img_data.tolist()
```

but is required PIL Image and NumPy.

Is there any chance to import these libraries in a lambda function or any other approach?

Thank you,
Samuele.

Comment: You can import any package that you bundle and upload with your Lambda function. That said, what format do you want the image's content in? It's almost certainly the case that you can do what you want using standard Python function, without the need to use NumPy at all (and maybe not even PIL).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to upload PIL as a Lambda layer and use the existing Numpy/Scipy Lambda layer. The Serverless framework tutorial linked to here is cumbersome in comparison.

For Numpy: You already have access to the publicly available Lambda layer for numpy that's automatically provided by AWS ("... to provide an example of how to use Lambda Layers, we are publishing a public layer which includes NumPy and SciPy... This prebuilt and optimized layer can help you start very quickly with data processing and machine learning applications." -- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/ ).

For PIL: Just use the instructions here: https://medium.com/@qtangs/creating-new-aws-lambda-layer-for-python-pandas-library-348b126e9f3e

I have done this for PIL myself and can confirm that it works.

Comment: Serverless framework can build a layer zip that the OP wants in less than a minute. Why would you say it's a mess?

Comment: "A mess" may have been too strong, so I reworded it. The problem is, every single time he wants to deploy any code change he has to rebuild it and upload. This becomes time-consuming and onerous when you are implementing a number of changes. Much more lightweight/painless to use Layers. Why not use layers to build the dependencies once?

Comment: Serverless framework supports layers. You have the option not to package your dependencies on every deploy. Also, even if you do, it has the cache builtin to avoid redundant work.

Comment: Fair enough, but the guide that you linked to was published pre-Layers and does not cover that use case. Using that exact tutorial for deployment is sub-optimal.

Comment: Please join our aws [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat). I can show you how you do it serverless framework.